# data repository that requires a DUA for secondary data analysis of medical research?

Tags: medicine, repository, nih, data-sharing

We are collecting medical observational data that eventually will be de-identified and made available for [secondary data analysis](https://www.ndacan.acf.hhs.gov/faq.cfm#q3) (to comply with the new [NIH Data Management & Sharing Policy](https://sharing.nih.gov/data-management-and-sharing-policy/about-data-management-and-sharing-policies/data-management-and-sharing-policy-overview#after)).  I'd like to find a data repository that requires potential researchers to submit a [DUA](https://www.nnlm.gov/guides/data-glossary/data-use-agreement) (data use agreement) to the repository's management.  Ideally the DUA specifies restrictions like (a) the recipient will not attempt to re-identify the participants, (b) the recipient will not distribute the dataset, and (c) the dataset will be used for only a narrowly-defined research question.

In a previous study, we selected the [NDACAN](https://www.ndacan.acf.hhs.gov/index.cfm) (National Data Archive on Child Abuse and Neglect; it specializes on these types of datasets) and [requires an DUA](https://www.ndacan.acf.hhs.gov/datasets/request-dataset.cfm) from secondary researchers.  I love how the repo assumes responsibility for determining if a secondary data analysis has a justifiable reason to obtain the dataset.

I'm on the university's CRDW (clinical research data warehouse) team, and we're involved in a lot of research that doesn't fit NDACAN's narrow mission and I'd like to find more options.  It's been difficult to find something similar.  I'm a big fan of open data repositories like [Dataverse](https://dataverse.org/) and [OSF](https://osf.io/), but since they can't require DUAs, I don't like them for granular medical data.  I'm comfortable stripping out the [~18 explicit variables](https://privacyruleandresearch.nih.gov/pr_08.asp), but I'm concerned that (current or future) techniques will be able to re-identify patients from details dataset.  So that's why I want a repository with oversight and DUAs.

I reviewed the 9 [generalist repositorie](https://sharing.nih.gov/data-management-and-sharing-policy/sharing-scientific-data/generalist-repositories)s, individually ruled out each of the 137 [domain-specific repositories](https://www.nlm.nih.gov/NIHbmic/domain_specific_repositories.html) on NIH's [Selecting a Data Repository](https://sharing.nih.gov/data-management-and-sharing-policy/sharing-scientific-data/selecting-a-data-repository) page, and read the 8 health sciences repos [suggested by Nature](https://www.nature.com/sdata/policies/repositories#healthsci).  I can't find a repo that accepts general medical research and requires a DUA, but I hope I'm simply overlooking one.

Two repos are close to my criteria: [NDA](https://nda.nih.gov/nda/data-contribution.html) (but we're not funded by the NIMH) and [Synapse](https://help.synapse.org/docs/Sage-Offerings.2965078125.html) (but the budget can't afford $30k+).

Does anyone have either (1) specific suggestions for conventional NIH-funded medical research or (2) strategies to identify appropriate data repositories (for research that initially included PHI)?